# How do you decide how to categorize a new idea? Patent? Present at a Conference? or Publish in a Journal?

Tags: publishability, patents

I came across a patent that proposes an idea for a device, and in the background section of the patent, other similar devices that were published in conferences (not even journals) were cited. Seriously nothing unique about the proposed design - not a jaw-dropping.

So consider the following scenario. You are sitting on a front porch, and you come up with an idea.

How do you know if it is worth to be filed as a patent, submitted to a journal, or presented at a conference?

Also, I came across a number of patents, and they were merely theoretical, without proving if the concept works flawlessly. So, how does this concept convince the people in the patent office? I’d like to know what elements make a patent too.

Comment: this question is too broad and big - a first step is a thorough patent literature research and then there are different reasons/strategies to file a patent or not. A patent does not prove something scientifically, it's rather a concept with a distinct purpose.

Comment: @user847982 Why is the question too broad and big?

Comment: @user2768 you answered the why, not the when...imho ;-)

Comment: @user847982 That seems like the crux of a the queston

Comment: I voted to close because this question has nothing to do with academia.  Perhaps law would be appropriate.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Academics produce patentable research

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18142/do-patents-have-to-be-original/18143#18143

Comment: @user2768 Academics also exhale carbon dioxide, but that doesn't make questions about breathing on topic.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist (I could ask an on-topic breathing question, but I digress) Academics are funded by bodies that expect commercial breakthroughs; the relationship with IP seems intrinsic.

Comment: @user2768 Some academics might be, but many are not; and this question is not about funding bodies either.  Similarly, some academics are funded by bodies that expect them to use boats, but questions about boats are not on topic.

Comment: @user2768: I agree!

Comment: @user847982: it is not broad at all!

Comment: I think the body of it needs work also.

Comment: Ronnie, you need to familiarize yourself with how this site works, or else you will continue to have the majority of your questions closed.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you know if it is worth to be filed as a patent, submitted to a journal, or presented at a conference?

**To commercialise, file a patent. To disseminate, publish a journal article or a conference paper.***

<sup>* Distinctions between journal/conference publication is dealt with elsewhere and, given the context, is seemingly out of scope.</sup>

> [Many patent ideas] were merely theoretical, without proving if the concept works flawlessly. So, how does this concept convince the people in the patent office?

US patent law demands [*usefulness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_(patent))

```
...an invention is "useful" if it...is capable of use...the doctrine prevents the
patenting of fantastic or hypothetical devices...
```

and European patent law demands [*industrial application*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_applicability)

```
...a patent can only be granted...for an invention which can be made...
```

These requirements should prevent granting patents for theoretical ideas.